# oddjob_mkhomedir doesn't run when logging in via SSH with Kerberos

Tags: centos, ssh, kerberos, sssd

I currently have a server which has Kerberos/SSSD/Samba to authenticate to Windows 2012 AD.

In `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` oddjob_mkhomedir is set as below:

```
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077 skel=/etc/skel
```

This was set by running `authconfig --enablesssdauth --enablesssd --enablemkhomedir --update`.

However when logging in via SSH with an AD account the home directory isn't created and the user simply ends up in root with `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash`.

Nothing in the error logs suggests either sssd isn't running as expected or the PAM module isn't being called.

Configs copied below:

/etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Port 22
ListenAddress x.x.x.x
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
KerberosAuthentication yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
debug_level = 7
domains = mydomain.co.uk
services = nss, pam

override_homedir = /home/%d/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash

[nss]

[pam]

[domain/mydomain.co.uk]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
cache_credentials = true
debug_level = 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at few things

```
  - is oddjobd running?
  - any messages related to this or PAM in authlog, messages
  - is SElinux enabled or enforced? check audit log for any AVC denial messages
```

Looking again at your sssd.conf, you may want to move `override_homedir` into the `DOMAIN` section, otherwise sssd seems to get home directory information from ldap.

Comment: also post output of 'getent passwd <some-ad-user>' and check 'ldap_user_home_directory' setting in sssd.conf

Comment: looking again at your sssd.conf, you may want to move override_homedir into DOMAIN section, otherwise sssd seem to get homedir info from ldap

Comment: Moving `override_homedir` into domain worked perfectly - thank you

Answer (score 5):

For future googlers: I just had a very similar problem on RHEL7.

Symptoms:

- `authconfig` had been run with '--enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enablemkhomedir --update'
- `sssd` had been (re)started
- `oddjob-mkhomedir` installed and `oddjobd` had been (re)started
- Still wasn't creating directories when logging in with an LDAP user.

Turned out that when I restarted `dbus` it all kicked into life - I think oddjob registers things with DBus that weren't getting picked up. Might be worth a shot!

Comment: Just found my own answer when I googled the exact same problem a few months later. <3 StackExchange.